# Document Highlights is null/empty when applying EdgeNGram custom Analyzer in Azure Cognitive search

Tags: azure, nlp, search-engine, azure-cognitive-search

We are building a document search engine for a client using Azure Cognitive search. We are trying to apply custom Analyzer on the "content" field (the contents of the files, base64 encoded).

Here is the Analyzers definition:

```
    "analyzers": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name": "pri_standard", 
        "tokenizer": "standard_v2",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "phonetic"
        ],
        "charFilters": []
    },
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name": "pri_custom_analyzer",
        "tokenizer": "EdgeNGram",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "lowercase",
            "pri_edgeNGram"
        ],
        "charFilters": []
    }
],
```

**And below is how it is applied at the index fields**

```
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "content",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": false,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": false,
        "facetable": false,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": "pri_custom_analyzer",
        "synonymMaps": [
            "industry-synonyms2"
        ]
    },
```

The token filters definition

```
  "tokenFilters": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.EdgeNGramTokenFilterV2",
            "name": "pri_edgeNGram",
            "maxGram": 15,
            "side": "front"
        }
    ],
```

And when we search the index, the Document Highlights field is always null. When we apply standard analyzer, it works properly, i.e. we get the Document Highlights returned correctly. What are we doing wrong here?